# HTML styling без СSS

Tags: html

Всем привет!
Прошу прощения за элементарные вопросы, но я учусь, учусь сам и спросить мне некого. 
В общем осваиваю HLML, до CSS ещё не дошёл. При стандартной установке параграфов и дивов - у меня текст растягивается по всей ширине экрана браузера, как и должно быть. Я понимаю, что CSS всё это поправит, но есть ли вариант внутри самого HTML документа разметит атрибуты дива или абзаца так, чтобы можно было сжать текст и сделать его наряднее?

Comment: Эти варианты были удалены из HTML именно потому, что есть CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 700px; color: #c00; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Tahoma';">
  Здесь ваш текст...
</div>
```

Ну то же самое применяемо и для p и всего остального.

Весь статичный CSS по сути ничем не отличается от `style="..."` в HTML.

Просто, когда вы добавляете все стили в сам HTML, со временем код становится очень запутанным. А если вдруг хочется что-то в нем изменить - приходится возвращаться и менять всё, во всех одинаковых style="..."

Особенно сложно работать с таблицами на чистом HTML. И тут ему на помощь приходит CSS - по сути, то же самое, просто записанное в другом месте. Вы просто собираете все стили вверху страницы, под тегом `<style>`, оставляя HTML таким же простым, каким он и должен быть.

Возвращаясь к тому коду, что был написан вначале. Его эквивалент на CSS:

```
<style> .bubu {width: 700px; color: #c00; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Tahoma';} </style>

<div class="bubu">
  Здесь ваш текст...
</div>
```

Что изменилось - всего лишь вместо style="..." дали вашему элементу новое имя (класс), к которому можно ссылаться через CSS и прикрутить к нему любой стиль. А если таких `class="bubu"` на странице будет 100 штук и вам захочется что-то в них изменить - всего лишь надо будет это изменение внести в `.bubu {...}` один раз... а не по 100 раз на каждом отдельном HTML-элементе.

Поэтому... параллельно с HTML как-раз надо CSS подтягивать. А вот позже уже в CSS можно научиться менять стили элементов при наведении курсора (CSS:hover), при клике (CSS:active) - делая страницу более "живой".

А есть еще и CSS-анимация.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Завтра попробую - искренне верю, что всё заработает - сразу поставлю галку о решении вопроса. Про CSS -  бесспорно и понятно, но я сейчас сконцентрирован на HTML и тренируюсь не только писать, но и читать код, ошибки искать и решать трудности тем, что есть. Я понимаю, что в CSS есть масса стилевых возможностей, но хочу сверстать первую свою страницу на HTML - чисто для практики.
С уважением,

Comment: @otimus prime Огромное спасибо, всё работает, как и писал выше - тренируюсь по всему, что связанно с HTML. Хотел добавить - свойство width работает и в процентах, в комплекте со свойством margin может позиционировать  div в горизонтальной плоскости как угодно

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/ma3s4o6c/ - есть еще такой удобный редактор для проверки всякого) [добавил пару прикольных примеров, которые возможно не знали]. По сути, для решения какой-нибудь HTML задачки, без проблем можно поискать и в ответах для CSS и применить то же самое к HTML